# Code Igniter overriden DB Active Record

Tags: php, database, codeigniter, overriding

I want to override the Active Record class (some functions of it at least). And I made a file called spj_DB_active_rec.php in a folder named "database" in my "application" folder but it does not work.

class name is spj_DB_active_record

```
<?php
class spj_DB_active_record extends CI_DB_active_record {

    function update($table = '', $set = NULL, $where = NULL, $limit = NULL) {
        if (is_array($set) && empty($set['modified'])) {
            $this->load->helper('date');
            $data['modified'] = date('Y-m-d H:i:s',now());
        }

        log_message('debug','TEST UPDATE '.date('Y-m-d H:i:s',time()));

        return parent::update($table, $set, $where, $limit);
    }

    function insert($table = '', $set = NULL) {
        if (is_array($set) && empty($set['modified'])) {
            $this->load->helper('date');
            $data['modified'] = date('Y-m-d H:i:s',now());
        }
        if (is_array($set) && empty($set['created'])) {
            $this->load->helper('date');
            $data['created'] = date('Y-m-d H:i:s',now());
        }

        log_message('debug','TEST INSERT '.date('Y-m-d H:i:s',time()));
        return parent::insert($table, $set);
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you share some information about what does not work? What are you expecting that to do?

Comment: You see it in the code. It's supposed to add "modified" and "created" to the insert/update if they have not been set. And First of all it should log the test message.

Comment: @Damien Pirsy I don't call the file. It's just an overriden file from codeigniter (or it's supposed to be).

Comment: I think that's your problem. Check my answer below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probably that's news to you, but CodeIgniter 2.0 doesn’t officially support extending the core Active Record class. So what you want to do is (unfortunately) not "just possible" by placing a class extending from it somewhere on disk.

But you can try this [workaround](http://robotslacker.com/2011/05/extending-codeigniters-active-record-class/).

Comment: Here is a [less hacky way of extending the DB Active Record class in Codeigniter](http://mineth.net/blog/extending-codeigniter-active-record-the-non-hacky-way/).